# How can I send a "ticket" view to a printer

Tags: printing, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-partialview

The goal of the application is to have all the tickets of a certain order (contains 1 or more tickets) printed out on paper.

I currently can load all the tickets from the order on my screen, but I'm not sure on how to proceed from here.

I can hit `ctrl+p` on my keyboard and pull up the `Print page` prompt, however the application is supposed to be used on a touchscreen by cinema customers. They wouldn't have access to a keyboard to hit `ctrl+p`.

> How can I automate the `ctrl+p` action or what would be the best solution?

PrintTicket.cshtml:

```
@model CinemaApp.TouchApp.Models.PrintTicketViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "PrintTicket";
}
@foreach (var t in Model.Tickets)
{
    @Html.Partial("TicketSummary", t)
}
```

TicketSummary.cshtml

```
@model CinemaApp.Domain.Entities.Ticket
<div class="well">
    <h3>
        <strong>@ViewBag.MovieName</strong>
    </h3>
    <strong>
        @ViewBag.HallName <br />
        Row: @Model.RowID.ID <br />
        Seat: @Model.SeatID.ID <br />
        TicketType: @Model.RateName.Name
    </strong>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fire off the print dialog by using the window.print() javascript method.

You can hide this behind a button click or use the document.ready function if you are using jquery.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_print.asp